# Consume HTTPS using mule

Tags: ssl, https, mule, ssl-certificate, esb

I am trying to configure a simple esb configuration, which exposes an http endpoint, but internally invokes a https service.

below is my configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd">


 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8096" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
```

-->

```
</http:request-config>

<flow name="secureddemoFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="Inside---" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/secureservice/esb" host="10.208.18.246" port="8443" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>

    <logger message="done---" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

This get deployed successfully, but when the endpoint is accessed I get the below exception :

```
 INFO  2016-03-30 12:08:01,443 [[secureddemo].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Inside---
ERROR 2016-03-30 12:08:01,531 [[secureddemo].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : {NullPayload}
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. No subject alternative names present (java.security.cert.CertificateException)
  sun.security.util.HostnameChecker:142 (null)
2. General SSLEngine problem (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException)
  sun.security.ssl.Alerts:192 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLHandshakeException.html)
3. General SSLEngine problem (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException)
  sun.security.ssl.Handshaker:1362 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLHandshakeException.html)
4. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync:349 (null)
5. java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem (java.io.IOException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient:245 (null)
6. Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester:287 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:142)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:91)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:255)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:138)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1328)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:808)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:806)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1299)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLUtils.executeDelegatedTask(SSLUtils.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:669)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLFilter.java:330)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:583)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:304)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.SwitchingSSLFilter.handleRead(SwitchingSSLFilter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.run0(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:134)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.access$100(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:31)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:157)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

********************************************************************************
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of issue happens when you try to access a service by a hostname that is not specified in the server certificate as SubjectAlternativeName (SAN). Since you are sending a request to 116.202.169.182, when that server returns its certificate to the client so it can be validated one of the checks performed is 'hostname verification' (basically: is this really who I want to communicate with?) expecting to find 116.202.169.182 listed.

The issue is not in the trust store or keystore you are configuring (in fact, you are just defining it but not actually referencing it in your `request-config` so I don't think it's being used) but with the server you are sending a request to. You could send the request using the hostname it defines in its certificate.

HTH

Comment: I have updated the code as per your suggestion and am now getting a handshake exception, could you please assist

Comment: Could you share the code update? If you are now not using the IP directly then the handshake error could be because what I mentioned about the ```tls-context``` not being actually referenced. I'd need to look at the code and the exception to be sure.

Comment: I have updated the code, with the one I am using now ( including your comments )

Comment: I don't see any changes. You are still using an IP as host and now you have no ```tls:context``` element defined nor the reference to it in the ```request-config```. The error, however, suggest that the server does not have any SANs defined in its certificate. Do you have control over it? Cause the certificate it's using is not properly set up.